# Upload pictures and data create dynamically codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter-3

I need to upload pictures and data create dynamically html and jQuery I use codeigneter framework and send the the all data to mysql.

This is code controller

```
public function Addtest() {
 $this->load->library('upload');
    $u=  $this->session->userdata('id_user');
   $files = $_FILES;
    $cpt = count($_FILES['sliderimg']['name']);
    $inputAll=  $this->input->post();

 $this->load->model('AddData');

 for($i=0; $i < count($inputAll['artilce']); $i++) {
         $_FILES['sliderimg']['name']= $files['sliderimg']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['sliderimg']['type']= $files['sliderimg']['type'][$i];
  //  $_FILES['sliderimg']['tmp_name']= $files['sliderimg']['tmp_name'][$i];

    $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
    $this->upload->do_upload();

    var_dump($_FILES);
    $data=  array(

        'id_user'=>$u,
        'description2'=>$inputAll['description2'][$i],
        'description1'=>$inputAll['description1'][$i],
        'art'=>$inputAll['artilce'][$i],

       $_FILES['sliderimg']['name']= $files['sliderimg']['name'][$i],


         $image_name =>$_FILES['sliderimg']['name'][$i],
    );

if( $this->AddData->Add_data($data)) {
       echo 'false';
} else {
       echo 'true';
}
```

and this the model code

```
 public function Add_data($artt) {
    extract($artt);

    $data = array(
        'Art'=>$art,
        'des1'=>$description1,
        'desc2'=>$description2,
        'picture'=>$image_name,
        'id_foreign'=>$id_user,
    );

    $this->db->insert('table',$data);
}
```

and the this the error output while I try to upload 2 pictures and data

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: image_name

and this is the `set_upload_options()` function

```
private function set_upload_options()
{   
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048000';
    $config['max_width']  = '20000';
    $config['max_height']  = '17680';
    $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;

    return $config;
}
```

and the `do_uplaod`:

```
public function  do_upload() {
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048000';
    $config['max_width']  = '2024';
    $config['max_height']  = '1068';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        return "false";
    }
    else
    {
        return "true";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the ```$image_name ``` variable defined?

Comment: In the Addtest controller, you have $_FILES['sliderimg']['name']= $files['sliderimg']['name'][$i], in data array, you sure this is not a typo?

Comment: I need to uplaot all the files pitcure

Comment: Shouldn't it be '=>' rather than '='?

Comment: Also  $image_name =>$_FILES['sliderimg']['name'][$i] should be  'image_name' =>$_FILES['sliderimg']['name'][$i], right?

Comment: oooooh where is my eyes !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
thanks but should be  'image_name' =>$_FILES['sliderimg']  yes

whta I sould ne do when I insert ful name pictuce wiht extension??